# differential perimeter of an ellipse

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

If I define an ellipse in polar system of $r$ and $\phi$ as shown in figure below, what is the length of differential element $(ds)$ on its perimeter in polar coordinate system?

**Note:** Please be advised that what mentioned in [this link](http://pages.pacificcoast.net/~cazelais/250a/ellipse-length.pdf) doesn't work for this question as they used $\theta$ to create a "*parametric*" form and so its definition is different from what we have here for $\phi$. Therefore, in spite of what mentioned there, one can derive the following formula for $r$ here:

$r(\phi)=\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\phi+b^2\cos^2\phi}}$

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article on [line element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_element#Orthogonal_curvilinear_coordinates) you can see that for polar coordinates you have

$$\mathrm ds^2=\mathrm dr^2+r^2\,\mathrm d\phi^2$$

This is essentially the Pythagorean rule: consider an infinitesimal right triangle with two legs, one tangential to a circle of radius $r$, the other radial. The distance element in radial direction is $\mathrm dr$, the distance element in rangential direction is $r\,\mathrm d\phi$. The square of the line element, which in this case acs as a hypothenuse, is the sum of the squares of these two infinitesimal distances.

To express the line element in your particular case solely in terms of $\mathrm d\phi$, you'll have to compute the derivative $\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm d\phi}$ which shouldn't be too hard since you already know a formula for $r(\phi)$. If in doubt, you can always [ask WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate%20ab%2Fsqrt%28a%5E2sin%5E2%CF%86%2Bb%5E2cos%5E2%CF%86%29%20with%20respect%20to%20%CF%86).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just for clarification, if we want to state the tangential element as $rd\phi$, is not necessary for $r$ to be the curvature radii anywhere in our problem? (like what we have for any $r$ in a circle; while in an ellipse $r$ is not necessarily the radii always)